# How to handle intranet application to work offline

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, excel

I developed a small expense report system used to replace an excel file that was very old.
The setup was pretty simple:

-UI is jquery, asp.net, simple css

-Back end is sql server 2005

-There are some additional tiers for the business layer.

Typical tiered application.  It's running on IIS 6 as an Intranet site.  It's a lot simpler to use then the excel sheet but of course there is the guy who doesn't seem to have an internet connection so how can he submit his expense report?

I thought of an offline system that serializes objects but this again seems to be a bit complex as eventually these serialized objects need to get back to the database layer.  I'm thinking more on the lines of just telling them to submit an excel spreadsheet to an "admin" who does have an internet connection and have them put in his / her expense report.  But I fear the "admins" will hate this.

Even if I whip up a desktop client application, I'd still have to hit the network to get to the data layer.

Any other ideas of how to handle the guy who cannot VPN or get on the network but once loved his excel application that I havent thought of?

Comment: Does he ever have an internet connection? For example, can he connect intermittently to sync his expense reports? How would he get the Excel spreadsheet to the admin without an internet connection?

Comment: How about informing _the guy_ that the year is 2011 and if he doesn't get on the internet and learn how to use a VPN he can't file expense reports. Just guessing he would figure it out _real fast_. (This should work provided _the guy_ isn't the boss, the bosses wife/uncle/cousin...)

Comment: @Cos Callis - I completly agree with you, and that is the path I'm headed in..however a lot of the site managers are on the road and connections to sources such as vpn are limited at customer sites such as ford, gm, etc.  The auto industry can be hectic sometimes...

Comment: ah.. as I read "_the guy_" I believed you were dealing with a singleton technological barbarian rather than a class of users who have difficulty connecting. See suggestion below (pending...)

Comment: @Cos Callis - Usually one turns into many, in this case we have many site managers where this could actually be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We implemented a few solutions where the users don't have a connection.  One was a WinForms app, and others were ASP.NET apps.  For the ASP.NET apps, we modified them to run using IIS on the laptop or client PC, since you can install IIS on a client OS.

What we ended up using as a pattern was to use a DataSet locally to hold/parse.manipulate data on the client PC, and then serialize it to an XML using the built in DataSet.WriteXml method.  Then we created an "Upload" screen (asp.net page or WinForms page) that shows the pending uploads.  This uploads the DataSet to an ASP.NET Web Service.  Since the DataSet object is serializable,  using it in a web service is the least amount of work.  The web service handles actually inserting/updating the database.

It is actually a lot less work than it sounds like, and the pattern has been so successful for us that it's become our standard method for handling disconnected apps.  The troubleshooting on these apps has been negligible, which to me speaks volumes for the simplicity and reliability, compared to other approaches we've tried.

Comment: So was I correct in that was one of my possible solutions to serialize the object and have it sit there until they do have a connection and maybe like you said bring up an upload screen to show them they have pending expense reports?

Comment: Yes. As you pointed out, it's a bit more complex, but using the DataSet object's ability to write and read XML makes that complexity manageable. Using a .NET service as the transport mechanism takes advantage of the .NET runtime's ability to serialize/deserialize DataSet objects simply. The added complexity is actually minimal, since calling a web service is almost no different from calling a function in your local code. Based on our experience, I'd say it's a good pattern to follow.

Comment: Just one final question, given that the object is serialized is it really a requirement to head on to the web service side?  Why can't I / wouldn't I be able to de-serialize the data and pass it to the db layer without having to use web services?  Given that the user "eventually" gets a network connection.

Comment: That is a perfectly viable option.  We did not use it in our situation because we have a bias toward using web services, particualrly where a number of clients are doing the same work.  if we need to make a change to the database, and the resulting code, it's easier to maniuplate the web service here at corporate than it is to coordinate updating multiple user's laptops/pc's in the field.  The more of the code we can have centrally located, the easier it is to maintain.  Web services are not necessary to the pattern, we just like to use them is all.

Comment: Which is just what I thought.  I was really thinking on this route but I definitely needed a nudge to get going.  Maybe this post serves as the nudge - Thank You will accept this answer unless I see something else as compelling +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement SQL Server Merge replication. There was a little bit of a learning curve, but I figured it out and implemented it in a couple of weeks so its definitely "do-able". You can have a desktop app that updates a sql server express db and then synchronizes the changes using replication at your choosing (maybe when the user is connected to the network).

**How Merge Replciation Works**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151329.aspx

Comment: Its an idea but this seems to be a lot of work involved. It would require the install of sql server express locally on each person's machine who may not have an internet connection.  And then test when the connection is made...to me it just seems like a lot of work.

Comment: This is true. In my situation the app polls an intranet web service I created about every 10 secs to find out when its connected becuase I was in a similar situation. But I would imagine that he has to be connected to the internet at some point, unless he is on a "thumb drive" network?

Comment: @JonH - BTW, once sql server express is installed on the client machine its just a matter of a few steps through a wizard on the main server and the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a variation of the email xls file to admin. Instead of the admin re-inputting the data, you could have them upload the xls file and your system could parse it and enter the data. Works quite well especially if the xls format is unified.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Office toolkit and macros build into the users Excel application the functionality to export the data into an XML dataset and transmit them when the opportunity permits. On the server end build an adapter that reads those XML files as they arrive and inserts the appropriate records as required.